# How to change primefaces autocomplete size dynamically?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, autocomplete

I am using primefaces autocomplete to select item. I don't know the items size.
    I fixed the autocomplete size. But whenever i select an item which is larger than 
    autocomplete size i'm not able to see the cancel option for that item.

```
please see the following attachment.
```

[image]

Code:

```
<p:autoComplete id="autoCompleteAssetField" value="#{child.assets}" 
completeMethod="#  {olmController.completeAsset}" var="asset"
 itemLabel="#{asset == null ? null :asset.tagNbr.concat(' - ').concat(asset.stdAssetName)  }"  itemValue="#{asset}" 
converter="#{olmAssetConverter}" forceSelection="true" size="30" scrollHeight="200"   multiple="true" >

</p:autoComplete>
```

Comment: Seems a CSS issue. Have you tried giving it a `width`?

Comment: even though i gave the width, i cannot predict the item size in the autocomplete. if the autocomplete has resize property like text area this problem will be resolved.

Comment: Please, post your tried code.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to add size attribute to p:autocomplete.
Try removing size attribute

```
<p:autoComplete id="autoCompleteAssetField" value="#{child.assets}" 
completeMethod="#  {olmController.completeAsset}" var="asset"
itemLabel="#{asset == null ? null :asset.tagNbr.concat(' - ').concat(asset.stdAssetName)}"  itemValue="#{asset}" 
converter="#{olmAssetConverter}" forceSelection="true" scrollHeight="200" multiple="true" />
```